# Use jQuery to slide in a textbox when hovering mouse over an area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Newbie jQuery questions. Say I have a label on a web page. I want the effect of sliding out an input box when hovering the mouse over the label. Any hint on how to assemble some existing jQuery support to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

[Example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywU5T/).

HTML:

```
<div class="HasHiddenInput">
    <div>My label</div>
    <div class="HiddenInput">
        <input .../>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('.HasHiddenInput').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.HiddenInput').stop(true,true).slideDown();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.HiddenInput').stop(true,true).slideUp();
        }
    );
});
```

Optional CSS:

```
.HiddenInput{
    display:none; /*Initially hidden*/
}
.HasHiddenInput{
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On hover animate a div to show the input:

$("#YourLabel").hover(function(){

```
  $("#DivWrappingInput").animate({
        width: 100,
    }, 500); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code or CSS, it's hard to say but something like this should work:

Assumign your HTML is like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label>Label 1</label>
        <input />
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('label').hover(function(){

      //Animate width to show the input box
      $(this).siblings('input').animate({'width':200 + 'px'});

    }, function(){

       //Animate width to hide input box
       $(this).siblings('input').animate({'width':0 + 'px'});

    }

});
```

You'll need to add a position of relative to the input box. You can animate the width of the input box if required as well. It depends on the context of use of the input box and label.